# Django admin, обратный inlines (inlines к родителю)

Tags: django, django-admin

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    field1 = models.ForeignKey(ModelC)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    field2 = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
    field3 = models.ForeignKey(ModelD)
```

В панели администратора можно сделать так:

```
AdminModelB(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ModelB

AdminModelA(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
    AdminModelB
    ]
```

Но реально ли сделать наоборот?

Интерфейс администратора предоставляет возможность создать запись в БД, на которую ссылается ForeignKey во всплывающем окне, и это круто.

Но как быть, если в частном случае, нужно ВСЕГДА и ТОЛЬКО создавать запись, а не выбирать из имеющихся ?

В случае с `ModelA`, мне при создании экземпляра, нужно ВСЕГДА создавать запись в `ModelC` на которую будет ссылаться запись в `ModelA`. В этом случае мне нужно нажимать на `+` и создавать запись во всплывшем окне, но случается так, что во всплывшем окне есть ещё одно `ForeignKey` поле, с которым нужно сделать то же самое, то есть нажать на `+`, и заполнить  форму.

Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы не нужно было нажимать на `+`, когда дело касается определённых полей?

Можно изменить форму, и переопределить метод, но я бы не сказал, что это DRY.
В связанных моделях форма может получиться на 12-15 полей, а в интерфейсе администратора нужно переопределять метод `get_fields` чтобы не показывать все поля одновременно (во-первых, не красиво и не удобно, а во-вторых, иногда нужно показать поля исходя из состояния модели, или что ещё страшнее,  из полей формы(т.к. `get_fields` не принимает `form`), например есть некий `status` или `type` имеющий `widget=forms.RadioSelect`)

Думал про [WizardView](http://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html), но не разобрался как интегрировать в админку.

Думал про обратный `ForeignKey`, но тоже не есть хорошо.

Думал и про `ManyToManyField`, вместо ForeignKey (в некоторых случаях это может быть уместно, к примеру, не один адрес, а несколько, не один номер телефона, а несколько), но тоже - изуверство.

Возможно где-то в документации не увидел, как это сделать или гуглил плохо, но как сделать - не знаю.

Буду благодарен за любую наводку.

***ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ***

Лучшее (DRY), к чему мне удалось прийти, это использование абстрактных классов.

То есть:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    class Meta:
    abstract = True
    field1 = models.ForeignKey(ModelC)

class ModelB(ModelA):
    field3 = models.ForeignKey(ModelD)
```

Данный пример будет не лучшей демонстрацией, но суть такова - когда нужен "обратный" `inlines`, или , другими словами `inlines` к родителю, то один из способов - наследование.

Answer (score 0):

Лучшее решение, которое я смог найти - [django-reverse-admin](https://github.com/narnikgamarnikus/django_reverse_admin). 
Здесь ссылка на мой форк. Работает с Django 1.11.1, но не рабоатет с `DateTimeField`.

Когда исправлю - обновлю этот ответ.

***ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ***

При редактировании объекта, созданный внутри формы родитель сохраняется, но не привязывается.